# Image processing extension for PostgreSQL Windows

Tags: postgresql

For my school project, we have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with PostgreSQL installed on it.

Now we want to manipulate images on it and find out are there some extensions for PostgreSQL like PostPic (http://drotiro.github.io/postpic/).

However this extensions require PostgreSQL to run on Linux (Ubuntu). Unfortunately we cannot move the server to another OS.

Does anyone know an image processing extension for PostgreSQL on Windows that has approximately the same features as PostPic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Unfortunately we cannot move the server to another OS.` Use another machine then. Postgres compiles and runs fine on any hardware, even an old desktop or laptop, or a Raspberry Pi ...

Comment: Where does it say it's Linux only? The installation guide may be for Ubuntu, but I don't see anything to suggest that you couldn't build it on Windows. You should probably read [this](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) first.

Comment: @NickBarnes In their Wiki they mention only Ubuntu (https://github.com/drotiro/postpic/wiki/quickstart). Getting PostPic working under Windows would be the perfect solution.

Comment: @Chris: I think only the `apt-get` command is specific to Ubuntu. None of it will help you in Windows, though... But you should just be able to take [their code](https://github.com/drotiro/postpic/blob/master/server/src/postpic.c) and follow [this guide](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/). The only extra step should be adding the dependencies/includes for the [GraphicsMagick library](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).

Comment: Thanks @NickBarnes